# how to get number of messages per second from MSMQ without using performance counter

Tags: msmq

procedure to get number of messages passed through queue per second or number of messages queue receiving per second, without using performance counter

System.messaging.MessageQueue.

Comment: Is it for testing purposes or for monitoring of a production environment?

Comment: Its for testing purpose. To test how many messages are being processed per time period without using performance counter.